# Как прикрепить TextView к концу LinearLayout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Помогите прикрепить этот TextView к низу LinearLayout, android:gravity-не помогает, android:layout_gravity, тоже.
[image: скриншот кода и превью]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С `LinearLayout` без костылей не получится. Именно для вашей задачи есть `RelativeLayout`.
Если хотите поизвращаться, то поставьте перед нужным `TextView` в разметку любой `View`, и выставьте у него `weight="1" layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: И правда, большое спасибо, использовал RelativeLayout!